# Cannot enable schedule a restart time

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Suddenly, my Windows 10 did a reboot without informing me. I went to settings and found this option:

[image]

I don't know what **We'll finish installing updates when you tell us to:** mean. Can someone explain?

If this means that it will ask me whether to reboot, well, this option is permanently disabled. It cannot be turned on. Why?

Comment: You can only schedule an updates to be installed if you have pending updates.....that's been true since the introduction of this feature in windows 10

Comment: make windows check for updates and if it finds updates go back to this option and see if its enabled.

Comment: So there is no way to have it permanently set to always ask me when to reboot?

Answer (score 0):

The way to permanently tell Windows 10 a set of ours to update outside of is to configure Active Hours.

In **Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Windows Update** click on **Change active hours** and then set the beginning and ending of the time you normally use the computer.

Once configured, Windows will automatically apply updates and perform maintenance outside of those hours.